# How to have multiple borders on div using css

Tags: html, css

I have searched alot, but i did not find any solution. I want to have border at bottom something like below image.
[multiple border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Qou.png) how can i have this type of border on div. I also want to have cricle image with shadow circle like this [circle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PusKM.png)

To add border at bottom in the first image i have added this code:

```
.login-wrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #338833, 0 2px 0 0 #883333;
}
```

but, It is not generating the desired output.

To get the desire output for second image. I have added the below code.

for circle image i have added this code:

```
<div class="login-wrapper" ng-controller="loginController">
    <div class="field-wrapper">
        <div class="login-img-wrapper">
            <img src="img/person.png" class="img-circle" />
            <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.login-img-wrapper img {
    border: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radious: 50%;
}

.login-img-wrapper .shadow {
    background-image: linear-gradient(130deg, white 50%, transparent 40%);
    opacity: .7;
    z-index: 15;
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    top: 0;
}
```

but this is not generating the same image. Please somebody help me.

What output i have got after aplying above defined css for second image [image: Cricle image after applying above defined css].

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a4osf4Lj/2/

This is a bit clumsy, but works ok.

*edit, added shadow

Comment: Your answer looks good. I think what i want it is exacly the same. I'll try it. What about second image ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kprdr3uL/2/ This is easy to use, but it doesn't fancy glass effect thought.

Edit* If you are using bootstrap, you can just use the img-circle class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start from where you can experiment with circle, shadow and border.

[Fiddle Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/L02977te/2/)
[Fiddle Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/L02977te/3/)  (Changed border/padding for image)

```
<div class="login-wrapper" ng-controller="loginController">
    <div class="field-wrapper">
        <div class="login-img-wrapper">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-100-100-9.jpg" />
            <div class="shadow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.login-img-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.login-img-wrapper:after,
.login-img-wrapper:before {
    z-index: -1;
    height: 4px;    
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 6px;
    right: 6px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    content:" ";
    position: absolute;
}
.login-img-wrapper:after {
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 3px;
    right: 3px;
}
.login-img-wrapper:before {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
}

.login-img-wrapper img {
    border: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
}

.login-img-wrapper .shadow {
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, white 50%, transparent 40%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: .7;
    z-index: 15;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 0;
}
```

**Update**

Using the new CSS `clip-path` shapes circles, ellipses, and polygons, more advanced masking and shapes can be done, though it still has bad browser support.

Read more about it here: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

For even more advanced clipping/shadowing (and better browser support) I recommend to start using SVG in combination with CSS.

As a start here is some ways to go: [Draw a crescent moon using SVG in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664244/draw-a-crescent-moon-using-svg-in-html)

Comment: Everything looks nice, but image circle not same as second original image. Could do something for that.

Comment: Did an update of my answer, added a second demo ... now you can see what I did and start changing it to how you want it to look like.

Comment: If you  look into second image, the shadow image is some rounded. could you add that. I think there if before or after should be added for inner round on shadow.

Comment: To accomplish that with different opacity in each part, some more advanced clipping is needed. Based on which browser support you want to have, I updated my answer with some links how this can be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `box-shadow`:

```css
.border-box {
 background:#ff0;
 display:inline-block;
 width:200px;
 height:20px;
 box-shadow:
  0 1px 0 #999,
  0 2px 0 #fff,
  0 3px 0 #999,
  0 4px 0 #fff,
  0 8px 0 #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-box"></div>
```

For your second image:

```css
.circle-image {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 display:inline-block;
 background:#ccc;
 border-radius:50%;
 position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}
.circle-inner {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 display:inline-block;
 border-radius:50%;
 position:relative;
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
.circle-inner:after {
 content:"";
 width:200px;
 height:90px;
 display:inline-block;
 background:rgba(255,255,255,.3);
 border-radius:200px 200px 0 0;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-image">
  <div class="circle-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you suggest me the solution for second image. Your answer is good for first image. What if i want that type of border all side.

Comment: Hello Mandy, I have edited my answer and try to solve your second problem

Answer (score 1):

You typed the `radius` spelling wrong.

```
.login-img-wrapper img {
    border: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Did it give you expected result?

Comment: i have spell wrong but, in css i am using bootstrap .img-circle css class.

Comment: add img-circle to div.

Comment: I have already tried your option, but i am not getting exact copy of the image. I have updated image what i have get after applying the css as mentioned in my code.

Comment: @Mandy did you change the image dimension.?

Comment: If you look both image, In original there is shadow which is circled from both side. There is some css required which i am not getting propperly. could you suggest dimesion which you are talking.

Comment: @Mandy I thought that you changed the dimension of image.